# Is it possible that the world will end in near future from a natural disaster?

Tags: futurology, science-fiction

Can any of these [apocalypse dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dates_predicted_for_apocalyptic_events) be true?

Is there any possibility that the human race will become extinct in the next 1000 years due to a natural disaster?

More Latest Findings:

Earth entering ‘6th extinction phase’, study finds http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/science/Study-finds-Earth-entering-6th-extinction-phase-many-species-including-humans-labelled-the-walking-dead/articleshow/47747974.cms

Comment: Hi Mohit Pandey. There are several other problems with this question as well. First, for the benefit of those who have not watched "2012", you are better off summarizing the relevant portion of the movie so that answerers are not required to watch it just to answer the question. Second, your second question is completely unrelated to the first. Third, we *like* to see questions that have had obvious effort put into them; this question reads more like a brief thought thrown onto the Internet to spark a discussion, rather than a well-thought-through question that needs a specific answer.

Comment: It may look like that this question has a broad scope. I just want to know about the possibility of any natural disaster(apocalypse) which may end human race in next 1000 years. Will update my question for the same.

Comment: Still **off topic** even with edits that improve the question itself.   If you relate to a more specific story you are contemplating, it might fit OK as there are a lot of questions along the lines of exploring ramifications of novel features of a setting (though they are fraught with being *too broad*)  maybe you could get a critical analysis on the items over at Skeptic.SE?

Comment: As written by JDługosz, your question is still too broad. And it would be hard to evaluate which answer is the best. If you are still interested in the 2012 movie, try to focus on one side of it, eg. overflooding the whole world. Furthermore, there are edits history, so no need to add an update: better to remove the parts that are completely unnecessary.

Comment: IMO, i don't want to focus on specific situation(like, flood) because its impossible that the whole world will drown. I am looking for the possible options which have some facts associated with them, that may lead to end the world.

Comment: There are 152 predictions for the past, all of which proved false. 9 predictions for the future are also based upon theological grounds, and so these are quite impossible too. Of the remaining 5 predictions only one is within the specified time interval, but that does not name any natural disasters. Speaking of which, it would require such a large scale disaster that is in itself very improbable. The best candidate would probably be an asteroid hitting Earth, if you wish to exclude human activities (nuclear war, bioengineered weapons, global warming, etc.), but even that has very low chances.

Comment: Earth entering ‘6th extinction phase’, study finds http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/science/Study-finds-Earth-entering-6th-extinction-phase-many-species-including-humans-labelled-the-walking-dead/articleshow/47747974.cms

Answer (score 2):

No, that movie was nonsense on top of nonsense.

As for that list, most of them are *in the past*.  Of the remaining, are any different in how they are determined than those already known to be past?

Comment: A couple of them are not.  The **Doomsday Argument** is one that was developed using statistical techniques and a few assumptions.  It's scary but it also has some flaws.

Comment: That's "failed before", too.  Look at [the formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population#Mathematical_approximations) and ask Wolfram-Alpha to integrate it. Some year where the total-ever-lived is less than 1/20 of today's value is a failed predition.

Comment: I agree - but didn't think of it that way.  Basically if you have a period of exponential growth, the Doomsday Argument will always tell you catastrophe is at the end.  Sometimes that's true but not with the frequency that the argument suggests.

Comment: The reference shows that growth was *hyperboloc* before settling into the current exponential growth curve. So, even more so: it *always* looks like we are near the end.